# Webpack SCSS / SASS precision option for Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack

Bootstrap 3 SASS requires a precision of 8

How would I set this in the Webpack build I am using textloader

```
// SCSS
{
    test   : /.*\.scss$/,
    loader : ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        "style", "css!sass"
    )
},
```

I have found this config but not for my loader.

```
scssLoader : {
    indentedSyntax : false,
    precision      : 8,
},
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your loaders

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!postcss!sass?precision=10'),
}
```

Set precision using `sass?precision=10`

Comment: I still need to test this - will revert when done - thanks.